# mysql workbench query does not display details about top 1000 rows

Tags: mysql-workbench

Please consider he following SQL Query displayed in MySQL Workbench after right clicking on a table and selecting option "Select Rows LIMIT 1000".

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM `mydatabase`.`mytable`;
```

However, as clear from above query, it doesn't says anything about top 1000 rows. Could anyone explain why is it like this.

Comment: What do you mean " it doesn't says anything about top 1000 rows"?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp There is no "LIMIT" word used in the SQL Query which is automatically generated after clicking.

Comment: Yes, WB works this way. When you select the menu option "Select Rows LIMIT 1000", it does not print the LIMIT part of query to the query editor. However, when you do specify LIMIT in the editor, it overrides the default 1000 and uses your value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM `mydatabase`.`mytable` Limit 0,2000;
```

that's because workbench by default has a limit statement 0,1000

Hope it helps

Comment: What if I don't wanna use LIMIT option at all. I wanna see all records?

Comment: You can do it this way [link](http://superuser.com/questions/240291/how-to-remove-1000-row-limit-in-mysql-workbench-queries)